# Can an AudioQueue's buffers be flushed

Tags: macos, core-audio, audioqueue

I'm trying to implement a "seek" function where the user can move the playback position on a slider and have my player start playing from the new position. The problem I'm encountering is that the AudioQueue still has buffers in its queue and will keep playing them. I haven't figured out any way to tell the queue to disregard the remaining queued buffers and start playing from a new buffer I pass in. I have tried pausing (AudioQueuePause) the queue and flushing the buffers (AudioQueueFlush) but that doesn't do what I expected. Do I need to toss the old audio queue and start fresh?

Answer (score 0):

You need to restart the audio queue.

You can do this by call `AudioQueueStop(audioQueue, true)` and then `AudioQueueStart()`.

The flag in `AudioQueueStop()` means "stop synchronously".

Comment: While AudioQueueStop does indeed stop the queue it also calls AudioQueueReset internally. I find that when using AudioQueueStop I have no idea how to determine when the reset is complete and I end up getting kAudioQueueErr_EnqueueDuringReset errors if I try to queue up buffers during the time the queue is resetting.

Any idea how to determine when reset is complete? Unfortunately I find Apple's documentation lacking in these sorts of details.

Comment: What’s wrong with it calling AudioQueueReset internally? Why not use the synchronous stop?

Comment: I was trying to stop it synchronously and ran into the troubles I described above. Apparently the reset takes time - or that is what I figured. I haven't found any real good documentation describing detailed internal behavior here. To solve my problem I basically just create a new queue in this particular situation. The amount of time to do this seems acceptable for my needs.

Comment: How long do the reset and recreate take?

Comment: I don't know how long the reset takes since I don't know when it completes. I didn't measure the recreate but just implemented it and tested using a slider to set the seek position. It certainly has the responsiveness I require from a UI standpoint.